# Redirct_to in application controller caused infinte loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After detect the browser page will we redirecte.

```
  def detect_browser
  redirect_to  "privacy"  if browser.ie6? || browser.ie7? || browser.firefox? 
  end
```

Causes the infinite loops.?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def detect_browser
  if(browser.ie6? || browser.ie7? || browser.firefox? ) &&
    params[:controller] != "privacy", params[:action] != "show"
    redirect_to  "privacy"  
  end
end
```